# Windows application very slow when using transparency

Tags: c#, transparency, performance

I am writing a windows application with C# in visual studio .net 2005.

In the form , there are some control with transparent Background; the form opens maximised and with full screen background.

The application runs very slow with high CPU usage.

Why is this?

Answer (score 7):

**1. Solution using property DoubleBuffered**

Sidenote: Only works if you have access to the control as `DoubleBuffered` is a protected property of Control. Similar as solution 2 (see code behind).

```
// from within the control class
this.DoubleBuffered = true;

// from the designer, in case you are utilizing images
control.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
```

[System.Windows.Forms.Control.DoubleBuffered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered?view=netframework-2.0)
[System.Windows.Forms.Control.BackgroundImageLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout?view=netframework-2.0)

**2. Alternative solution using SetStyle + OptimizedDoubleBuffer:**

Sidenote: The control paints itself, window message `WM_ERASEBKGND` is ignored to reduce flicker, and the control is first drawn to a buffer rather than directly to the screen.

```
control.SetStyle(UserPaint | AllPaintingInWmPaint | OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

[System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetStyle(ControlStyles, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle?view=netframework-2.0)
[System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles?view=netframework-2.0)

**3. Alternative solution using SetStyle + DoubleBuffer:**

Sidenote: Similar as `OptimizedDoubleBuffer`, due to legacy reasons it remained in the codebase.

```
control.SetStyle(UserPaint | AllPaintingInWmPaint | OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

[System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetStyle(ControlStyles, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle?view=netframework-2.0)
[System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlstyles?view=netframework-2.0)

Comment: Beware that DoubleBuffering requires more memory, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314197/advantages-and-disadvantages-when-using-doublebuffer-on-control

Comment: More info on SetStyles: DoubleBuffer vs OptimizedDoubleBuffer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967228/controlstyles-doublebuffer-vs-controlstyles-optimizeddoublebuffer

Answer (score 5):

Thats because the GDI+ transparency implemented in .NET 2 is not ideally implemented, as [Bob Powell explains](https://web.archive.org/web/20141227200000/http://bobpowell.net/transcontrols.aspx).