# ScrollableControl draw border around entire control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I'm building custom user control that is based on `ScrollableControl`.
Right now I'm trying to add border around my control (similar to border that DataGridView has)

I'm able to draw border using:

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(AutoScrollPosition.X*-1, AutoScrollPosition.Y*-1);
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, Color.DarkBlue, ButtonBorderStyle.Dashed);
```

but this draws border around ClientRectangle, not around whole control:
[image]

As you can see in the above picture, border isn't surrounding scrollbars as it does in DataGridView.

Can I draw border around entire control so that scrollbars get included in area surrounded by border?

EDIT:
Based on [Textbox custom onPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414693/textbox-custom-onpaint) I am able to draw custom border, by overriding `WndProc` but I get this weird looking border flickering:

[image]

Here is full code I have so far:

```
internal class TestControl : ScrollableControl
{
    private int _tileWidth = 100;
    private int _tileHeight = 100;
    private int _tilesX = 20;
    private int _tilesY = 20;

    public TestControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        UpdateStyles();
        ResizeRedraw = true;
        AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(_tilesX*_tileWidth, _tilesY*_tileHeight);
    }

    private bool _test = true;
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            if(_test==value) return;
            _test = value;
            Update();
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hwnd);
    struct RECT
    {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }
    struct NCCALSIZE_PARAMS
    {
        public RECT newWindow;
        public RECT oldWindow;
        public RECT clientWindow;
        IntPtr windowPos;
    }
    int clientPadding = 1;
    int actualBorderWidth = 1;
    Color borderColor = Color.Black;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        //We have to change the clientsize to make room for borders
        //if not, the border is limited in how thick it is.
        if (m.Msg == 0x83 && _test) //WM_NCCALCSIZE   
        {
            if (m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                RECT rect = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(RECT));
                rect.left += clientPadding;
                rect.right -= clientPadding;
                rect.top += clientPadding;
                rect.bottom -= clientPadding;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(rect, m.LParam, false);
            }
            else
            {
                NCCALSIZE_PARAMS rects = (NCCALSIZE_PARAMS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(NCCALSIZE_PARAMS));
                rects.newWindow.left += clientPadding;
                rects.newWindow.right -= clientPadding;
                rects.newWindow.top += clientPadding;
                rects.newWindow.bottom -= clientPadding;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(rects, m.LParam, false);
            }
        }
        if (m.Msg == 0x85 && _test) //WM_NCPAINT    
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            IntPtr wDC = GetWindowDC(Handle);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(wDC))
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height), borderColor, actualBorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                    borderColor, actualBorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, borderColor, actualBorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                    borderColor, actualBorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
            }
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(AutoScrollPosition.X, AutoScrollPosition.Y);

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        var offsetX = (AutoScrollPosition.X*-1)/_tileWidth;
        var offsetY = (AutoScrollPosition.Y*-1)/_tileHeight;

        var visibleX = Width/_tileWidth + 2;
        var visibleY = Height/_tileHeight + 2;

        var x = Math.Min(visibleX + offsetX, _tilesX);
        var y = Math.Min(visibleY + offsetY, _tilesY);

        for (var i = offsetX; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (var j = offsetY; j < y; j++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Beige, new Rectangle(i*_tileWidth, j*_tileHeight, _tileWidth, _tileHeight));
                e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("{0}:{1}", i, j), Font, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(i*_tileWidth, j*_tileHeight, _tileWidth, _tileHeight));
            }
        }

        using (var p = new Pen(Color.Black))
        {
            for (var i = offsetX + 1; i < x; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, i*_tileWidth, 0, i*_tileWidth, y*_tileHeight);
            }

            for (var i = offsetY + 1; i < y; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, i*_tileHeight, x*_tileWidth, i*_tileHeight);
            }
        }

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, AutoScrollPosition.X*-1 + 10, AutoScrollPosition.Y*-1 + 10, 35, 14);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("TEST", DefaultFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), AutoScrollPosition.X*-1 + 10, AutoScrollPosition.Y*-1 + 10);

        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(AutoScrollPosition.X*-1, AutoScrollPosition.Y*-1);

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, Color.Red, actualBorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.None,
                    Color.Red, actualBorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.None, Color.Red, actualBorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
                    Color.Red, actualBorderWidth, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }

    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignMode)
        {
            base.OnScroll(e);
            return;
        }

        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.First)
        {
            LockWindowUpdate(Handle);
        }
        else
        {
            LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
            Update();
            if (e.Type != ScrollEventType.Last) LockWindowUpdate(Handle);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (VScroll && (ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
        {
            VScroll = false;
            LockWindowUpdate(Handle);
            base.OnMouseWheel(e);
            LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
            Update();
            VScroll = true;
        }
        else
        {
            LockWindowUpdate(Handle);
            base.OnMouseWheel(e);
            LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
            Update();
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr hWnd);
}
```

Can this flickering be fixed?

Comment: You write `ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle,..` and then complain about the border being draw around the ClientRectangle ???

Comment: @TaW I've tried this.Width instead of ClientRectangle.Width, but it looks like scrollbars are drawn on top

Comment: Does the UC have an BorderStyle? I suggest Single..

Comment: @TaW I'm using `ScrollableControl` as base so there is no `BorderStyle` property. I'm trying to draw in manually.

Comment: Ah, that's right. borders only come in from UserControl. Which makes me curious: Why not go for a real UC? Also: You could set the ClientSize(!), but not the ClientRectangle (!?). Not sure if that would help, though..

Comment: @TaW I've searched a bit because I couldn't decide what to pick as base class. I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1322499/965722 I thought that `ScrollableControl` will be a good choice because I don't want any extra stuff, I'd like to get max performance as possible, but I see that I'm trying to recreate `UserControl` from `ScrollableControl`

Comment: _Can this flickering be fixed?_ Did you turn on DoubleBuffered?

Comment: @TaW yes I have `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);` flickering only affects border.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967228/controlstyles-doublebuffer-vs-controlstyles-optimizeddoublebuffer) on 'details' of the two types..

Comment: @TaW I'm setting both `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true); SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);` I've put my currect code in updated question.

Comment: Hm, I usually prefer the direct DoubleBuffered proerty over setting styles but it ought to work the same (?).. - When does it flicker? When moving, on each redraw? When drawing child controls?...?

Comment: @TaW As You can see on second image in my question the flickering only happens when I resize my control, control is fine, only black border isnn't painted correctly. I don't have any child controls. I'm drawing content of my control in `OnPaint`. I'll try to set DoubleBuffered and compare results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141500/discussion-between-taw-and-misiu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by overriding `CreateParams`:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= NativeMethods.WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT;

        cp.ExStyle &= (~NativeMethods.WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
        cp.Style &= (~NativeMethods.WS_BORDER);

                cp.Style |= NativeMethods.WS_BORDER;

        return cp;
    }
}
```

and here is required `NativeMethods` class:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    public const int WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT = 0x00010000;
    public const int WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0x00000200;
    public const int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;
}
```

below is the result:

[image]

Comment: Both your question and your answer are useful, but it seems you are reinventing the wheel. Have you ever thought of deriving from `UserControl`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply derive from `UserControl`. It has built-in support for showing scrollbars and also has built-in support for showing borders.

All of built-in features of `UserControl` can be added to your control which is derived from `ScrollableControl` but with some additional try and error effort or taking look at [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UserControl.cs,b56599f057d7b666) of `UserControl`. But using `UserControl` class you can simply have those features.

**Show Border**

To show border, it's enough to set its `BorderStyle` to `FixedSingle` to get desired feature:

[image]

**Show Scrollbars**

To gain scroll feature, it's enough to set its `AutoScroll` to true and also set a suitable `AutoScrollMinSize` for control. Then when the width or height of the control is less than width or height of given size, the suitable scrollbar will be shown.

**Custom Border Color**

I also suppose you want to have different border color for the control, then it's enough to override `WndProc` and handle `WM_NCPAINT` and draw custom border for the control like this:

[image]

In above example, I've used the same technique which I used for [Changing BorderColor of TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420512/3110834) with a small change, here I checked if the `BorderStyle` equals to `FixedSingle` the I drew the border with desired color.

**Enable the designer to act like a Parent Control at design time**

If you want to enable it's designer to be able to drop some controls onto your `UserControl`, it's enough to decorate it with `[Designer(typeof(ParentControlDesigner))]`. This way, when you drop your `UserControl` on form, it can host other controls like a panel control. If you don't like this feature, just don't decorate it with that attribute and it will use `Control` designer by default which doesn't act like a parent control.