# How to draw a border around Panel on Button Hover?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to draw a border around a panel when the mouse is hovered on a particular button so that it will give a sort of highlight effect and on MouseLeave event the border will be gone. How to achieve this? I am new in Winform app development.

PS- I have drawn a rectangle in the panels paint event but i want to show the rectangle on mouse hover. I have tried Invalidate() but nothing happens.

Comment: You can change [panel border color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43419785/3110834) the same way that you can change [textbox border color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43419785/3110834).

Comment: To understand the difference between overriding `OnPaint` and handling `WM_NCPAINT`, see a scrollable panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please follow my answer closely, I've tested it locally, co it should be ok for you as well:

**1)** Add a new class to your project, name it `MyPanel.cs`
**2)** Replace default text of the class with:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
   public Pen MyPen;

    public MyPanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        MyPen = Pens.Red;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(MyPen, 0, 0, ClientSize.Width - 1, ClientSize.Height - 1);
    }
}
```

*This is inside a namespace of your application, don't forget about this*

**3)** Go to `Form1.cs [design]`
**4)** Add a new button from the toolbox `toolbox->button`
**5)** Double click some free space inside the form to generate `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`
**6)** Back in the designer, click the button once and in the properties box switch to `events` (small icon of a lighting bolt)
**7)** Double click `MouseHover` to generate `private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Now our setup is ready so let's put things into the action:

**8)** Instantiate MyPanel class right under `public partial class Form1 : Form`:

```
 MyPanel p = new MyPanel();
```

**9)** In `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` we can setup this instance and add it to the form's controls:

```
        p.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        p.Size = new Size(100, 100);

        Controls.Add(p);
```

**10)** Last thing we need to do is to change border color on hover of button, so let's do that in `private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)`:

```
        p.MyPen = Pens.Yellow;
        p.Refresh();
```

*And that's it :)*

Ps: If you want to make the border gone then use `MouseLeave` event and change `MyPen` of the panel to `Pens.Transparent`

Comment: This is working! However i have a panel having many labels, Think of it as i want to give that panel a border. How to wrap this panel around that ? is there any way ?

Comment: @K.Ajay please accept and upvote my answer if possible