# Advantages and Disadvantages when using DoubleBuffer on control

Tags: c#, .net

Default, Windows controls don't have DoubleBuffer. When I use it, I can reduce flicker. Why does it not use by default in Windows Controls.

And anyone can tell Advantages and Disadvantages when using DoubleBuffer on control.

Thanks.

Comment: Double-buffering uses more resources and isn't always needed.

Comment: It makes painting slower.  Any control that's painted after yours will stay unpainted for longer.  Showing a white or black rectangle until it does.  That's perceived as flicker too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double buffering technique is used when the drawing we wish to create has many details,and it is time consuming to draw even with a fast computer.In this technique instead of drawing in the screen,first drawn into an image and then the image drawn into the window.

WinForms is purposed for creating forms with UI elements (ComboBox, TextBox and etc.) first, so that's why it is not using Double Buffering by default.

Double buffering is purposed for graphic development.

So... Double buffering uses more memory but works faster, and there is no need to use it, when there is no many drawings

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Double buffering is a technique used
>   to make drawing intensive applications
>   faster and appear smoother by reducing
>   flicker. The basic idea is to take the
>   drawing operations used to paint your
>   application and apply them to an
>   off-screen canvas. Once all of the
>   drawing operations have finished, this
>   off-screen canvas is then 'pushed
>   forward' to the surface - or drawn as
>   a single image onto the control. This
>   gives the user the appearance of a
>   much faster application.

DoubleBuffer is very memory intensive, if your system have less memory in that case you might face problems of memory crunch.

> A final consideration about the double
>   buffering idea described here is that
>   this is neither fully optimized or
>   without its disadvantages. While
>   double buffering is a great way to
>   reduce the flickering of your Windows
>   Forms painting, it is memory
>   intensive. Essentially, using twice
>   the effective memory: the
>   application's screen image as well as
>   the off screen image. Also,
>   dynamically creating a Bitmap object
>   for every paint event is extremely
>   expensive as is using the
>   Graphics.DrawImage to push the
>   off-screen image to the surface of the
>   Form. The DoubleBuffer control style
>   performs all of these optimizations as
>   is generally the most efficient way to
>   do double buffering.

You can read more on this [here](http://windowsclient.net/articles/windowsformspainting.aspx)